# Threshold for matches in OpenCV's DescriptorMatchers

Tags: opencv

is there a way to set a threshold for potential matched pairs of image descriptors calculated by DescriptorMatcher in OpenCV's features2d?

In detail, I have a Bruteforce-Matcher with which I want to calculate descriptor pairs of two images and only pairs with a minimum distance of *threshold* should go in matches.

```
BFMatcher matcher(NORM_L2, true);
vector<DMatch> matches;
matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);
```

Thank's for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I did some more reading and found some interesting Posts like [How to use flann based matcher, or generally flann in opencv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695034/how-to-use-flann-based-matcher-or-generally-flann-in-opencv) and figured out my own way ;-)

First I used FlannBasedMatcher to match the calculated descriptors. After that I sorted the matches (they get sorted by distance in ascending order by default). Created a second DMatch vector and just added the matches which had a distance below a distance-threshold chosen by me. Thats it. This way I can also choose the top N matches it the threshold is selected to bad.

May not be the best / cleanest way but it's a quick solution which is ok for the prototypal situation.

Answer (score 1):

Use **radiusMatch** instead of **match**

```
matcher.radiusMatch(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches, your-threshold);
```

Comment: Wrong. The documentation says: "For each query descriptor, finds the training descriptors not farther than the specified distance.", while the OP is asking *only pairs with a minimum distance of threshold*.

Comment: i ran the code. please don't base your answers only on documentation.

Comment: It clearly says *maxDistance* in the source code: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/a26bed16e64401d790930dc73dd29462bddd8d2c/modules/features2d/src/matchers.cpp#L1139

Comment: what is the difference exactly between "descriptors not farther than the specified distance" and "pairs with a minimum distance of threshold"?

Comment: They are exactly the opposite, @Moe!

Comment: While I agree with @aledalgrande, it seems that this solution will beat the purpose of the matching, so I think jstr actually meant maximum, in which case the solution of Moe should work.